Late Binding, when the library is loaded into the process memory?
In the late binding mechanism, when exactly the referenced library is physically loaded into the process memory?
I have a .net (c#) program which have a bunch of:
 [DllImport("Foo.dll")
 private static extern void CALL_TO_A_METHOD_1();

 [DllImport("Foo.dll")
 private static extern void CALL_TO_A_METHOD_2();
 ...

As I understand, the library Foo.Dll will be loaded into the process memory in the first method call, whatever the method is.
So, if it happens that my program didn't call any external methods, the Foo.Dll library will not be loaded the process memory, right?
Update: It seems the answer for this question confirms my understanding

So yes, this is very dynamic. This doesn't happen until your code actually lands on a statement that calls the pinvoked function. The technical term is "late binding" as opposed to the more common early binding used by the Windows loader for native code.

